# How to allow decimal quantity on get_refreshed_fragments in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have this code that allow me to send decimal quantities in My Cart page:

```
function customize_quantity_field() {
    // Add min value to the quantity field (default = 1)
    add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'min_decimal');
    function min_decimal($val) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Add step value to the quantity field (default = 1)
    add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'nsk_allow_decimal');
    function nsk_allow_decimal($val) {
        return 0.01;
    }
    
    // Removes the WooCommerce filter, that is validating the quantity to be an int
    remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');
    
    // Add a filter, that validates the quantity to be a float
    add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');
}
add_action('wp', 'customize_quantity_field');
```

When going to My Cart page I can see the decimal value on quantity field.
But when I make a change then hit the button "Update Cart" the Ajax call (?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments) is done then update the cart with int value on my quantity field.
How to keep my decimal value and make that price calculation with that decimal value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many test it working now, decimal are allowed on show cart and update cart with the updated code:

```
// Removes the WooCommerce filter, that is validating the quantity to be an int
remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');

// Add a filter, that validates the quantity to be a float
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');

function customize_quantity_field() {
    // Add min value to the quantity field (default = 1)
    add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'min_decimal');
    function min_decimal($val) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Add step value to the quantity field (default = 1)
    add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'nsk_allow_decimal');
    function nsk_allow_decimal($val) {
        return 0.01;
    }        
}
add_action('wp', 'customize_quantity_field');
```

OR

```
// Removes the WooCommerce filter, that is validating the quantity to be an int
remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');

// Add a filter, that validates the quantity to be a float
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');

function customize_quantity_field() {
    function change_quantity_min_value($args, $product) {
        if (is_cart()) {
            $args['min_value'] = 1; // Set the minimum value to 1 for the cart page
            $args['step']      = 0.01; // Quantity steps
        }
        return $args;
    }
    add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'change_quantity_min_value', 10, 2);
}
add_action('wp', 'customize_quantity_field');
```

The problem was that the '*woocommerce_stock_amount*' hook should not be inside the *customize_quantity_field* function.
I need this function because I'm going to carry out checks to apply it to specific products.